# how do i send drop down select values to another page i have code but i can't get drop down select values

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

how do i send drop down select values to another page i have code but i can't get drop down select values into another page? i want to send size values to another page `header('location:shoppingcart.php?size='.$sizes.'');` also not working. i have tried form action on `size form` then `addtocart not working`.. problem with `button` when i used `submit button` instead of `button` then it's working but with `submit button`  `add to cart` function will not work?

is that possible i can send `$_POST['size']` values to another page without submit form?

**javascript **

```
<script language="javascript">
function addtocart(id){
document.form1.id.value=id;
document.form1.command.value='add';
document.form1.submit();
}
</script>
```

**Php Code**

```
$sizes=$_POST['size'];
include("cart/functions.php");
if($_REQUEST['command']=='add' && $_REQUEST['id']>0){
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
addtocart($id,1);
header('location:shoppingcart.php?size='.$sizes.'');    
exit();
}
```

**Form 1 for Add To Cart**

```
<form name="form1" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" />
<input type="hidden" name="command" />
</form>
```

**Size Form**

```
<form action="" id="size1" name="size1" method="post">
<div class="details clearfix">
<p class="item">
<label style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; ">Choose your size:</label>
<select style="background-color:#CCC" name="size" id="size" >
<option>Select</option>
<option value="Small">Small</option>
<option value="Medium">Medium</option>
<option value="Large">Large</option>
<option value="XL">XL</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**Add To Cart Button**

```
<div class="buy">
<?php 
$query3=mysql_query("select * from products WHERE id='$id' ");
$row3=mysql_fetch_array($query3);
?>
<input type="button" class="button1" value="Add To Cart" >
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: yes you can do that by simply using jquery .change(function(){}) and the $.post..but your code it not clear..that's why i am not sure that about anything

Comment: @Peeyush please is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to send the data to some other page as soon as the drop down values changes then you can try like this with jQuery:

```
$("#size").change(function(){
  var dropdown_val=$(this).val();
  $.post("shoppingcart.php", { size:dropdown_val},function(data){
   console.log(data);
} );
});
```

on the shoppingcart.php side you can receive the value in `$_POST['size']`

Comment: @AdamSmith you need to try my JQuery code on the same page where your select box exists

Comment: i used jquery on the same page where my drop down values are showing

Comment: @AdamSmith can you please post the whole page code at pastebin.com whatever you tried with my code...so i can take a look.

Comment: @AdamSmith you need to paste my jQuery code inside $(document).ready(function(){}); at 100th line of your product item page.........Apart from this i think your basic concept about jQuery is not clear so please brush up on them then try to workout on this much amount of code.

Comment: peeyush jquery on the 100 line which is use for slider ... only i don't think so there is a link with that problem

Comment: @AdamSmith yes inside the 100th line function

Comment: problem with button when i used submit button instead of button then it's working but with submit button add to cart function will not working?

Answer (score -2):

Use the action event

```
<form action="process.php" id="size1" name="size1" method="post">
```

I don't know if this is a school project or something weird you are working on or just very early stages, but the whole page looks very odd in the way it is written.

Comment: post the code of what doesn't work then people can see what is wrong.  But your whole code is broken if you expect that to work.  You aren't actually displaying any values from your database

Comment: i can send size values to another page?

<select style="background-color:#CCC" name="size" id="size" >
<option>Select</option>
<option value="Small">Small</option>
<option value="Medium">Medium</option>
<option value="Large">Large</option>
<option value="XL">XL</option>
</select>

Comment: Yes.  Learn about .CSS style sheets.

Comment: Is the value of size in the URL on shoppingcart.php after submitting?  Do some basic trouble shooting

Comment: @Steve: What the heck does learning about CSS have anything to do with this? CSS has zero to do with this.

Comment: @ patrick, oh I misread his comment where he had the code just above.  I read it as "i can send style values to another page".  My mistake... :P  I thought it odd at the time, hence my brief answer.

Comment: @steve problem with button when i used submit button instead of button then it's working but with submit button add to cart not working?

Comment: @steve add to cart function will not work after using submit button